# SonarQube installation with Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sonarqube

I would like to set up SonarQube with Microsoft SQL Server (MSSQL). As of 05/27/2015, the requirements clearly state that SonarQube is supported with MSSQL 2008 and MSSQL 2012.

Has anyone tried setting up SonarQube with MSSQL 2014? If so, can you please let me know how it worked or did not work for you? If you are of knowledge of SonarQube's architecture, can you let me know if there are any architecture constraints that will prevent this from working?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using it with MSSQL 2014 as described in the Ranger's guidance on [SonarQube Installation guide](http://aka.ms/vsartdsq). It's been working fine.

Regards - Jean-Marc

Comment: Indeed MS SQL 2014 is not yet listed in the requirements page (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements) because we don't have yet any automatic regression tests using this latest version of MS SQL but should work fine.